# Javascript OR jQuery display random element on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website for my custom themes on a blogging site. I want to have a review section, but I only want to have one review per page refresh. I was wondering if there is any way to write a script with jQuery or javascript (I'm not sure which one) to pick a random element from an array (All of the reviews will have a seperate element, each person having a different div ID with a different review) and display that element inside a div called #reviews, and hide the other elements? It sounds very confusing, but basically I need either jQuery or javascript to pick a review and put it in the review section. If anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it's impossible to use jQuery without Javascript because jQuery IS a Javascript library.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffPNs/2/)

```
<aside id="reviews">
    <article class="review"></article>
    <article class="review"></article>
    <article class="review"></article>
</aside>​
```

and

```
var $reviews = $('#reviews .review').hide();
$reviews.eq(Math.random()*$reviews.length).show();​
```

But unless you plan on revealing the other reviews at some point (slider, or pagination), you should really do this server side. Sending people content just to hide it is a little wasteful.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work, or your recreating it didn't work? Refreshing that link will give you one of the `.review`s randomly.

Comment: Thank you , very simple but powerful solution

Answer (score 1):

jQuery *is* JavaScript.  To get a random element from an array, use Math.random():

```
function getRandomElement(a) {
    return a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
}
```

Comment: How would I go about putting all of the elements in an array and displaying the random element in #review?

Answer (score 0):

I would use knockout.js which is great for binding JavaScript objects to DOM. You can fill an array of your object and data-bind it to the div. Each time you will bind a random element of the array to the div. The data binding is very simple:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>


// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
 this.firstName = "Bert";  
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

For more examples see the great tutorials in:
[Knockout.js tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro)